# How do I create a data frame after using groupby.tail

Tags: pandas, group-by, tail

I want to create a plot on terrorist groups within my data, I have grouped and used.tail however I cannot plot the data

```
-<bound method Series.count of terrorist_group
-Revolutionary Armed Forces of Colombia (FARC)     -105
-Al-Qaida in the Arabian Peninsula (AQAP)          -142
-Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan (TTP)                   -157
-Maoists                                           -165
-New People's Army (NPA)                           -210
-Boko Haram                                        -234
-Al-Shabaab                                        -325
-Islamic State of Iraq and the Levant (ISIL)       -374
-Taliban                                           -775
-Unknown                                          -7973
-dtype: int64>
```

---

```
terrorgroup=year2013.groupby("terrorist_group").size().sort_values(inplace=False)
gtf=terrorgroup.tail(10).count
gtf
```

Comment: You forgot the paranthesis: ```gtf=terrorgroup.tail(10).count()```

Comment: You probably want `terrorgroup.tail(10).value_counts()`